# Blocking websites with wireless router

Tags: router, website

Is it possible to block websites with all wireless routers.  How can I find out if a certain router has this administration feature, specifically the **TP-LINK WR340G**?

Comment: did u not check the manuals? Explain in detail, the steps you have tried out... #research

Answer (score 3):

It may be easier to do that sort of filtering with a service such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/).

Answer (score 1):

To know, you should probably check the user guide for a given router if it's not an advertised feature. The specific router in question does have a decent firewall with support for [blocking traffic based on IP, port, domain, or MAC address](http://www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp?class=&content=fea&pmodel=TL-WR340G). You can view the domain filtering options for this router on their [TL-340G simulator](http://www.tp-link.com/simulator/TL-WR340G/userRpm/index.htm).

Comment: `Advanced Settings -> Security -> Domain Filtering`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want maybe just to get a router which is compatible with advanced firmware like dd-wrt, tomato etc.

List of alternative firmwares:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_routing_software

Comment: You know that's a terrible list, right? It doesn't even include DD-WRT.

Comment: this looks better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Routing_software